# How to setup Micrometer for Resilience4j retry?

Tags: java, kotlin, resilience4j

I am using micrometer for my Retry annotation that I have at top of the function.

https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/micrometer#retry-metrics

This retry works but I need micrometer for the Retry.

```
@Retry(name = "retryCallCourse"))
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleCourseManagement(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        String path = ControllerTk.getServiceUri(req); 
        String requestData = ControllerTk.getRequestData(req); 
        return ControllerTk.invokeService(restTemplate,path, req.getMethod(), requestData);
    }
```

I read the micrometer documentation, and it seems not to work with @Retry annotation